# Input groups button bigger than input in Bootstrap 3 using Jumbotron container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code for the form:

```
<div class="container-full">

      <div class="jumbotron text-center" style="background-color:transparent; margin:auto">
        <form name="verifyForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
           <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-xs-1" style="margin: auto;" ng-class="{'has-error': verifyForm.verifyCode.$invalid}">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" style="min-width:15em">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <button id="filter" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="submitForm();" style="background-color:#6e5cbf; color: #ffffff">
            > 
          </button></span>
           </div> 
        </form>
      </div>
```

The problem I have is when I add a button to the button group, it is bigger than the input box:

[image: Button is bigger than the input box]

How can I stop this from happening? Thanks

Comment: Without a fiddle it's hard to tell - but it seems like the button takes 100% height and that the containers height is to blame.

Comment: If I do <span class="input-group-addon">@</span> instead of a button it works fine. However I need a button because I want to submit the content from the input box.

Comment: again, hard to tell without a fiddle. your button is probable an inline-block type when span is simply inline - that's what causes the erratic behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it by changing the button to a span with `role=button` on the parent and switching a few styles around, like so

```
<div class="container-full">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center" style="background-color:transparent; margin:auto">
        <form name="verifyForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-xs-1" style="margin: auto;" ng-class="{'has-error': verifyForm.verifyCode.$invalid}">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" style="min-width:15em">
                <span class="input-group-addon"  style="background-color:#6e5cbf;" role="button">
                    <span id="filter" onclick="submitForm();" style="color: #ffffff">
                        >
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

While the bootstrap documentation doesn't say anything about buttons, it does say

> We do not support multiple form-controls in a single input group.

Looking at the styling of buttons vs. form-controls I'd assume that the restriction extends to buttons as well.

---

It's going to look like this (image)

[image]

---

Comment: that's for screen readers (accessibility) and it also styles the cursor as a hand icon.

Comment: Seems like Bootstrap doesn't submit the form. I am using it with Angular.js.

Comment: nevemind was an angular js problem sorry about that!

Comment: No worries! Glad you got it sorted out. I didn't see your earlier comment till after you put in the last comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add form-group for these input and button element.

something like

```
<form name="verifyForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
       <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-xs-1" style="margin: auto;" ng-class="{'has-error': verifyForm.verifyCode.$invalid}">
          <div class="form-group">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" style="min-width:15em">
          </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <button id="filter" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="submitForm();" style="background-color:#6e5cbf; color: #ffffff"></button>
            </span>
         </div>
       </div>
    </form>
```

It will differentiate those two blocks and you can write cutom classes on top of that

Answer (score 0):

Your `button` has class `.btn` which has following style:

```
.btn{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px; //this is what making it to extend space
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143; //and this too
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

So the work-around will be override those properties. Add a class say 'special' to the button and override following attributes:

```
.special{
    padding:0px !important;
    line-height:1
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/6bupuLof/)**

Answer (score 0):

Why is everyone making it complicated? Just put this and y'all will be fine.

**This:**

`<input class="btn btn-outline-primary form-control-sm" type="button" Value="Send" />`

**instead of:**

`<button class="btn btn-outline-primary form-control-sm">Send</button>`

Boom. We done.